# TypeError while trying to wait until 2 elements appear on webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I need to wait until 2 elements with specified selectors appear on the page. In Java Selenium has a special ExpectedCondition, but not in Python, so I found a solution on another question page here and now have this code:

```
    def test_another_document_creation(self, WebDriverFixture):
        driver = WebDriverFixture
        page = MainPage(driver)
        page.new_document_create()
        page.upload_file(os.getenv("AGREEMENT_FILE_PATH"))

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda browser: len(browser.find_elements(*MainPageLocators.PAGE_ONE)) == 2)(driver)
```

With this code, I have the following error: `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

I'm not sure how lambda function should be written here, so I tried to add brackets to the function itself and driver variable to make them as one expression, like this:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until((lambda browser: len(browser.find_elements(*MainPageLocators.PAGE_ONE)) == 2)(driver))`
But nothing changed, still `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

Comment: What's the ExpectedCondition you use in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

```
len(browser.find_elements(*MainPageLocators.PAGE_ONE)) == 2
```

evaluates to a bool and this is not acceptable type in the lambda function as shown in the error message

Why don't you try

```
while len(self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"*MainPageLocators.PAGE_ONE")) != 2:
      time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Because I didn't think to do it xd
Thank you, it really did work!